# My text is not sitting at the top of the box when I add floating images

Tags: html, css

I'm having a problem with text inside a div that keeps moving down whenever I add a floating image.

Here is the html code:

```
<div class="clearfix" style="border: 3px solid #4CAF50; padding: 5px;">
Lorem ipsum 
</div>

<p></p>

<div class="clearfix" style="border: 3px solid #4CAF50; padding: 5px;">
<img src="https://campingannie.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/wenzel- Alpine8Dome1.jpg" alt="GENERIC PIC" style="width: 200px; height: auto; float: right;">
Lorem ipsum....
</div>

<p></p>

<div class="clearfix" style="border: 3px solid #4CAF50; padding: 5px;">
<img src="https://campingannie.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/wenzel-Alpine8Dome1.jpg" alt="GENERIC PIC" style="width: 200px; height: auto; float: right;">
<img src="https://campingannie.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/wenzel-Alpine8Dome1.jpg" alt="GENERIC PIC" style="width: 200px; height: auto; float: right; clear: right;">
Lorem ipsum...
</div>
```

and the css:

```
.clearfix::after {
content: "";
clear: both;
display: table;
}
```

Here is a jsfiddle. where everything is working fine:
http://jsfiddle.net/bnspz9j2/  `

But when I implement the code, the text keeps moving down, whenever I add a floating div. Here is a picture of the problem. Text is fine in the first box, moves down when I add a floating image, and moves down again when I add another floating image:

[image]

I've no idea what the problem is and it's driving me mad. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: What actually you are looking for? are you want display image side by side???

Comment: I want the text to remain at the top of the box when I add the two floating images (I want the images below each other). The Jsfiddle shows the result I wish; the image shows the problem I am having: space is introduced above the text whenever a floating image is added. I wish to eliminate the space.

Comment: If jfiddle has the result you wish, why not using the code in it? it's the bootstrap class "clearfix" that does the trick, it fixes elements alignment whether has been assigned a float (left, right).

Comment: As I said in the original post, the jsfiddle code is exactly the code I am running. It works in jsfiddle, it does not work when I run it.

Comment: Then you must provide the whole thing because the issue doesn't come from the code you provided.

Answer (score -1):

Sarah, if it is working in jsfiddle and not in your implementation it could be a reset file. Do you have any?

Because even when I run it here in stackoverflow snippet it works.

```css
.clearfix::after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: table;
}
```

```html
<div class="clearfix" style="border: 3px solid #4CAF50; padding: 5px;">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
</div>

<p></p>

<div class="clearfix" style="border: 3px solid #4CAF50; padding: 5px;">
<img src="https://campingannie.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/wenzel-Alpine8Dome1.jpg" alt="GENERIC PIC" style="width: 200px; height: auto; float: right;">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
</div>

<p></p>

<div class="clearfix" style="border: 3px solid #4CAF50; padding: 5px;">
<img src="https://campingannie.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/wenzel-Alpine8Dome1.jpg" alt="GENERIC PIC" style="width: 200px; height: auto; float: right;">
<img src="https://campingannie.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/wenzel-Alpine8Dome1.jpg" alt="GENERIC PIC" style="width: 200px; height: auto; float: right; clear: right;">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
</div>
```